# c++ How to pass 2d array to the function and how to read it

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I have

```
char buffer[220][800]={0};
```

I want to pass to it to a function

```
void myfunction( 2d array, int column, int row);
```

in myfunction definition , I want able to do

```
for(c =0 ; c<column ; ++c)
{
     for(r =0 ; r<row ; ++r)
     {
        if(array[c][r] ==0)
        {

           do something
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays naturally decays to pointer to its first element. But that doesn't mean an array of arrays will decay to a pointer to a pointer, but rather to a pointer to an array.

Take your example

```
char buffer[220][800];
```

That is of type `char[220][800]`.

When it decays to a pointer to its first element, it will be the same as `&buffer[0]`, which is of type `char(*)[800]`. Which have to be the type of your argument:

```
void myfunction(char (*array)[800], int columns, int rows);
```

Inside the function, the variable `array` can be used just like an array of arrays, as in `array[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`void myfunction(char [][800], int columns, int rows);`

Regarding the traverse of the array, yes: two loops are needed. But don't forget that you are working with chars. I don't know if you want them to be compared with zero. That is null:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

By the way, with vectors you wouldn't need to pass the two remaining parameters